# Textarea doesn't keep its contents after a form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, post, textarea

I am trying to keep a textarea content in its field after a form submission.

I lose the content of the textarea each time I click on the submit button as textarea gets cleared.

The form and the textarea code:

```
<form method="post" action="ProcessText.php" role="form" id="TextEntry">
                    <fieldset style=" height: auto; margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 4%; margin-right: 4%; border: solid 1px black !important; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; border-bottom: none;">
                        <legend style=" width: auto !important; height: auto !important; border: none; font-size: 17px"><b>Text Entry</b></legend>
                        <div class="form-group" style=" margin-bottom: 3px;margin-top:20px; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%;">
                            <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 5px"><label for="TextArea" class="label label-primary" >Text Area</label></div><br>
                            <div style="position: relative"><textarea style=" resize: none" id = "TextArea" name="TextArea" class="form-control"
                                                                      rows = "19"
                                                                      cols = "50"
                                                                      style=" width: auto; height: auto; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid#c0c0c0; " placeholder="Add some text"><?php if(isset($_POST['TextArea'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['TextArea']); }?></textarea></div>        
                        </div>
                        <br><button style="float: right; margin-right: 5%" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit">Analyse</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

The form and textarea are in index.php page which submits to another page (i.e. ProcessText.php). The submission runs successfully and ProcessText.php page receives the posted data as expected.

I have looked through the forum for answers and tried many solutions like putting the following code within textarea tags:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])) { 
         echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea1']); }?>
```

I also tried this code within textarea tags with no any good:

```
<?php echo $_POST['TextArea'] ? $_POST['TextArea'] : "" ?>
```

Just for clarification, the index.php page code that holds the textarea:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Sorting Form</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Styles.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style> </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

            <div style=" background-color: white; border: 1px solid Grey; 
                 border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888888; 
                 width:50%; max-width: 50%; height: 90%; margin-top:3%; margin-left: 
                 3%; margin-right:auto; overflow: hidden; float: left;">
                <form method="post" action="ProcessText.php" role="form" id="TextEntry">
                    <fieldset style=" height: auto; margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 4%; margin-right: 4%; border: solid 1px black !important; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; border-bottom: none;">
                        <legend style=" width: auto !important; height: auto !important; border: none; font-size: 17px"><b>Text Entry</b></legend>
                        <div class="form-group" style=" margin-bottom: 3px;margin-top:20px; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%;">
                            <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 5px"><label for="TextArea" class="label label-primary" >Text Area</label></div><br>
                            <div style="position: relative"><textarea style=" resize: none" id = "TextArea" name="TextArea" class="form-control"
                                                                      rows = "19"
                                                                      cols = "50"
                                                                      style=" width: auto; height: auto; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid#c0c0c0; " placeholder="Add some text"></textarea></div>        
                        </div>
                        <br><button style="float: right; margin-right: 5%" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit">Analyse</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>


            <div style=" background-color: white; border: 1px solid Grey; 
                 border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888888; 
                 width:40%; margin-left: 700px; height: 90%; margin-top:3%;">
                <fieldset style=" height:90%; margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 5%; margin-right: 4%; margin-bottom: 10px; border: solid 1px black !important; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; border-bottom: none;">
                    <legend style=" width: auto !important; height: auto !important; border: none; font-size: 17px"><b>Result</b></legend>
                    <div class="Notes" style=" margin-bottom: 3px;margin-top:40px; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; height: 75%; width: auto">

                        <?php
                        session_start();

                        // Display Custom Field Value
                        echo '<pre>';
                        echo nl2br("The Submitted Paragraph:\n".$_SESSION['Text']."\n\n");
                        echo nl2br ("Number of Words: " . $_SESSION['number']."\n\n");
                        echo nl2br("Word Frequency in Descending Order:\n");
                        print_r($_SESSION['results']);
                        echo '</pre>';
                        session_unset();
                        session_destroy();
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </div>

        </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

The ProcessText.php page code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Sorting Form</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Styles.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php session_start(); ?>

        <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


            $text = $_POST['TextArea'];
            $wordcount = word_count ($text);
            $words = utf8_str_word_count($text, 1);
            $frequency = array_count_values($words);
            arsort($frequency);
            $_SESSION['results'] = $frequency;
            $_SESSION['number'] = $wordcount;
            $_SESSION['Text'] = $text;
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();

        };

        function utf8_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $charlist = null) {
            $result = array();


            if (preg_match_all('~[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}' . preg_quote($charlist, '~') . ']+~u', $string, $result) > 0) {
                if (array_key_exists(0, $result) === true) {
                    $result = $result[0];
                }
            }

            if ($format == 0) {
                $result = count($result);
            }

            return $result;
        }

        function word_count ($string) {
            $words_to_count = strip_tags($string);
            $pattern = "/[^(\w|\d|\'|\"|\.|\!|\?|;|,|\\|\/|\-\-|:|\&|@)]+/";
            $words_to_count = preg_replace ($pattern, " ", $words_to_count);
            $words_to_count = trim($words_to_count);
            $total_words = count(explode(" ",$words_to_count)); 
            return $total_words;
        }

        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ever heard of CSS?

Comment: Why does the bottom piece of code not have the php part in it?

Comment: How are you getting BACK to `index.php` after the form submits to `ProcessText.php`? Straight include() or a header() redirect? If its a header redirect, thats not going to contain the $_POST vars.

Comment: i see `TextArea` and `TextArea1`

Comment: What does `ProcessText.php` do with the input? If it stores it in a database, `index.php` can perform a database query to get it, and then display it as the initial contents of the textarea. Or `ProcessText.php` could put it in a session variable, which `index.php` can read.

Comment: @IncredibleHat it is a header redirect? can you clarify please, I don't get it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry for such a messy code

Comment: Dont say sorry to me, say sorry to the person whos got to maintain it in the future. ;p

Comment: Looks like you are already stuffing it into `$_SESSION['Text']` ... so use that in your form `textarea`... ? did you try that? BTW `session_start();` must be before any output. Put it at the top of your page before the html starts.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I have edited my question to have the ProcessText.php page's code

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes indeed, but I just need to use the $_POST instead.

I have been told from someone expert that relying on $_SESSION  variables is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you are facing is that you are POSTing to a different script, and then doing `header("location: index.php");` back to index.php. This loses all $_POST vars, and there is no way to add them into the header redirect (browsers POST, not server header redirects).

So, you need to change your direction...

Since you are already stuffing the textarea content in a session variable `$_SESSION['Text']`, you can use this on your index.php:

```
<textarea name="TextArea" ...otherstuff... ><?php 
      echo (!empty($_SESSION['Text']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['Text']) : '' );
      unset($_SESSION['Text']);// optionally clear after re-iterating it
?></textarea>
```

Some caveats you need to address in your `ProcessText.php` page though:

- Move `session_start();` to the very top before any html or echo output.
- Add `session_write_close();` before your `header();exit;`.
- Heck, all that 'html' above your `header()` needs to go as well.

If you don't want to use sessions... because some expert told you they are terribly unreliable and useless:

A) POST to the ***same page*** that will be re-displaying your form (ie index.php)

or

B) Setting up a main branch script which handles all submits, but has no html of its own. This then would do a straight `include('index.php');` of which page you should be given (thus the $_POST vars will exist). However this method requires a bit of planning and discipline in setting up all your scripts and html blocks.

Comment: I have addressed all your points in my code and it worked well. The only exception is when I put: 
`<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['Text']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['Text']) : '');?>` between `textarea` tags, I get like a 32-long whitespace character string when I run the script.

It seems that `$_SESSION['Text']` never gets empty, even before POSTing, or is it the `htmlspecialchars` function that causes this to happen?

Comment: A 32-long whatnow? That sounds awfully like garbage-in-garbage-out syndrome. You may want to do a `trim()` on the original `$_POST['TextArea']` when you assign it to be used. It should not have that whitespace unless the form submitted it (php just doesn't add it itself, and definitely not during an unset).

Comment: Oh, and be sure you have a `session_start();` at the very top of your index.php (before any html output). Not sure if you had that or not, but you do need it if not.

Comment: Hahaha!! It was just the silly textarea closing tag that was formatted and placed in a new line. When I counted the spaces between the closing tag and the last character before it, it was 32-long whitespaces...

I thought that PHP was just like Java where you can auto format the code appearance without suffering from any problem because of the generated whitespaces. 

Many thanks to you for your massive help @IncredibleHat

Comment: You know... I thought it might be dead space in the HTML itself... but, glad you spotted it and confirmed! Gotta be careful with textareas since they behave with the end tag (while input elements are a single tag). Glad you got that figured out!

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you are catching the error set `$_SESSION['textentered']`. e.g if you do not want to duplicate values in your database.
Example:

```
//condition that makes you echo back entered values when there is an error
if($rowexists){
$_SESSION['textentered']=$_POST['textentered'];
}
```

Then in your textarea do something like:

```
<textarea><?php if(isset($_SESSION['textentered']) && $_SESSION['textentered'] !=''){echo $_SESSION['textentered'];} ?></textarea>
```

This worked for me.